# R data frame flattening/reshape

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df in R of the form

```
a,1
a,4
a,2
b,6
b,8
b,4
c,4
c,5
c,2
```

I want to represent df in the form

```
a,1,4,2
b,6,8,4
c,4,5,2
```

What is a faster way to do this transformation in R, especially if my data frame was of a larger size??

Comment: This is really a [long to wide dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format), but without column names or a sufficiently unique index. It's all fixable, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% set_names(paste0('V', 1:2)) %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(var = paste0('X', row_number())) %>% spread(var, V2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `dplyr` and `reshape2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
dat=dat%>%group_by(V1)%>%dplyr::mutate(id=row_number())
as.data.frame(acast(dat, V1~id,value.var="V2"))

  1 2 3
a 1 4 2
b 6 8 4
c 4 5 2
```

*Data input :*

```
dat
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  a  4
3  a  2
4  b  6
5  b  8
6  b  4
7  c  4
8  c  5
9  c  2
```

EDIT : Timing

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
    acastmethod=acast(dat, a~id,value.var="b"), 
    dcastmethod=dcast(dat, a ~ id , value.var = "b"),
    tidyrmethod=spread(dat, key = id, value = b),
    xtabmethod=xtabs(b ~ a + id, data = dat)

)


Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval  cld
 acastmethod 1.872223 2.035528 2.237846 2.210701 2.349068  3.783507   100 a   
 dcastmethod 3.124578 3.405817 3.626199 3.579038 3.815807  4.887430   100  b  
 tidyrmethod 4.025684 4.477290 4.765803 4.725326 5.035862  6.140385   100   c 
  xtabmethod 5.054490 5.529382 6.378615 5.714020 6.047391 61.242200   100    d
```

Comment: What is the variable before and after ~ in the formula in acast referring to?

Comment: @ I provide my sample data as `dat`

Comment: ok. Why not use dcast instead of acast? That way need not use as.data.frame. Is acast faster or so?

Comment: Sure, also why not use reshape itself with id var, time var and values instead of the cast fn.s. I ask in particular as my dataset is very large ;)

Comment: Hi, you can check it , also if you do need a faster speed , please try to look at `Rcpp`

Comment: You meant Rcpp?

Comment: yeah, it is typo , sry ~

Comment: Thanks. Great solution overall. Accepted.